# Can't import external JS library to Rails app via Webpacker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack

Can't import external JS library in Rails app via Webpacker.

The JS lib is:
https://github.com/jvcalderon/gist-client

I installed it with npm install and can see it in node_modules at the moment.

My package.json:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "@rails/actioncable": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/activestorage": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/ujs": "^6.0.0",
    "@rails/webpacker": "5.4.3",
    "gist-client": "^1.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.6.0",
    "turbolinks": "^5.2.0",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12"
  },
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3"
  }
}
```

Current application.js

```
// This file is automatically compiled by Webpack, along with any other files
// present in this directory. You're encouraged to place your actual application logic in
// a relevant structure within app/javascript and only use these pack files to reference
// that code so it'll be compiled.
//= require jquery3
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

import Rails from "@rails/ujs"
import Turbolinks from "turbolinks"
import * as ActiveStorage from "@rails/activestorage"
import "channels"
import "../../assets/javascripts/direct_uploads.js"
require("jquery")

Rails.start()
Turbolinks.start()
ActiveStorage.start()
```

Rails and Webpacker:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4', '>= 6.1.4.1'
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
```

So, when I try to import node with adding command

```
require("gist-client")
```

to my application.js, I see a error in my browser console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'
    at Module.<anonymous> (gistClient.js:451)
    at Module../node_modules/gist-client/lib/gistClient.js (gistClient.js:453)
```

(same thing when I try import instead of require)

I'm a newborn in Rails. And the task seems pretty easy, but I spent too much time trying to solve it. Thank you in advance for any help!

Comment: Try how it says here: https://github.com/jvcalderon/gist-client#basic-use

Comment: razvans, thanks!
Tried it. When I put "const GistClient = require("gist-client")" in my js file, I get this type of error:
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

Comment: What js file? application.js? It's impossible to get require is not defined.

Comment: 1) if I put "const GistClient = require("gist-client")" in my separate **assets/javascripts/my_file.js** , i've got 
_Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined_
2) if I put "const GistClient = require("gist-client")" in **application.js** , I've got error:
_Uncaught TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'exports' of object '#<Object>'_

Answer (score 0):

not sure that is right, but it works for me:
added import "gist-client" to application.js

added to my js-file:

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function() {
   const GistClient = require("gist-client")
   const gistClient = new GistClient()
})
```